# como puedo redireccionar de un view a otro en swift 5 Xcode 12

Tags: ios

Soy nuevo en swift per me gustaría saber como puedo redireccionar de un viewcontroller a otro en swift 5, estoy haciendo login con json y quiero condicionar si el usuario es valido lo envíe a otro view controller con el contenido.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que has intentado?. Haces el login a un servicio REST?

Answer (score 0):

En la vista :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez que recibes el json :

```
let Main = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
                                guard let inicioVC = Main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InicioController") as? InicioController else {
                                    return
                                } 
                                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(inicioVC, animated: true)
```